# Get rid of Google Translate on a Link?

Tags: php, html, google-translate

following situation: I have one domain "cn.domain.tld" which is configured with a rewrite rule in Apaches configuration to not to show the original page but to make use of Google Translate to translate it to Chinese. This works fine.

Then I have a second domain "domain.tld" whic hshows the original, untranslated content.

Now on my webpage I offer two links to the end user, one goes to "domain.tld" and one to "cn.domain.tld". Switching from untranslated to "cn.domain.tld" works properly, my pages are shown in Chinese. But now when somebody clicks the link to "domain.tld", this is opened within Google Translate too and no longer shown in native language but translated!

So my question: how can I tell Google Translate within a Link to no longer change the Link-URL so that one can leave the Translate-contetxt and get back to the original page after clicking such a link?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: @MagnusErikssonwhat exactly is wrong with my question? It describes the problem completely and non-ambiguous. I'd guess you read questions before posting your prepared text-blocks :-/